# error while using async in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I am trying write a restapi using express framework and node.js. I am facing an error which I am unable to find out the root cause. I am getting the following error while trying to execute the code :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'node_type' of undefined` where 'node_type' is a value that comes from a function

```
var GdbProcess = require('../../dao/gdb/processnds')
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var async = require('async');

exports.executeService =  function(req,res){
//Make the process object to query
var manualProcessQuery = new Object();
manualProcessQuery.index = req.params.processmap;
manualProcessQuery.key = "pid";
manualProcessQuery.value = req.params.pid;
manualProcessQuery.event = req.params.event;

var tempDataNodeToExecute = new Object();
//This function returns  an object (dataNodeToExecute) to execute
GdbProcess.getParametersbyNode(manualProcessQuery,function(err,dataNodeToExecute){
    if(err) res.send(err);
    tempDataNodeToExecute = dataNodeToExecute;
    var isSystem = false;
    if (tempDataNodeToExecute.node_type =="system"){
        isSystem = true;
    }

    var count = 0;

    async.whilst(
        function () { return isSystem },
        function (callback) {
            //execute the function
            executeSystem(dataNodeToExecute,function(err,executionStatus){
                if (err) callback(err);
                count++;
                if(executionStatus=="completed"){
                    manualProcessQuery.value = tempDataNodeToExecute.pid;
                    manualProcessQuery.event = "completed";
                         GdbProcess.getParametersbyNode(manualProcessQuery,function(err,dataNodeToExecute2){
                        if(err) callback(err);
                        tempDataNodeToExecute = dataNodeToExecute2;
                        if (tempDataNodeToExecute.node_type == "manual"){
                            isSystem = false;
                        }

                    });

                    callback();
                }
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            if(err) res.send(err);
            res.send("success");
        }
    );
});

}



var executeManual = function(prosNodeToExecute,callback){
//do something
callback (null);
}

var executeSystem = function(prosNodeToExecute,callback){
//do something
callback(null,"completed");
}
```

When I debug the code, i clearly see that node_type is available. Can someone help me to find the root problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the new object tempDataNodeToExecute and use dataNodeToExecute instead of it, and it is a good practice to check for null of an object before using its property so that the program does not crashes.

Comment: Yes.. I tried dataNodeToExecute. But its the same result.  I was intentionally not checking for null of an object to help me find out where the heck it crashes